# Assign value to a string dereference operator

Tags: go

I'm new to go, pardon me if this is a regular question, How does the assignment to a string dereference operator works below?

```
package main    

import "fmt"

func main() {
    course := "Docker Deep Dive"
    changeCourse(&course)
}

func changeCourse(course *string) {
    fmt.Println(course) // prints the memory address of course since it is a pointer
    fmt.Println(*course) // prints the value since * is dereferenceing the pointer

   // Issue
    *course = "Docker Extended" // *course is a string, how does the assignment works here.
    fmt.Println(*course) // prints "Docker Extended"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` (also know as indirection operator) is used to “dereference” pointer variables, dereferencing a pointer gives us access to the value the pointer points to.
In this case: `*course = "Docker Extended"` basically you are saying to the compiler: store the `string` "Docker Extended" in the memory location `course` refers to.

Comment: In simple words deference returns a variable, so that we could access and assign values? @Tinwor

Comment: In simple words the indirection operator returns the value of the variable while reference operator return the address of a variable. In Go you can also use the new built-in function to get the pointer. @SrinivasDamam

Comment: Just like any dereference, this will cause a nil pointer dereference panic if the pointer is nil, so make sure to check first.